# Can't get out of grub terminal

Tags: boot, 18.04, grubrescue

After a boot-repair, ironically, my grub is broken. When I starty laptop, it boots into terminal,  it's written 'grub>_'

I searched for solutions, like 'set prefix, set root and insmod normal' and 'linux /boot/....' . None of these 2 solutions are working. Can anyone help with that?

Note: Due to another boot issue, I am not able to boot via a live usb.

Comment: [Recatux](https://www.supergrubdisk.org/rescatux/) has some tools to repair GRUB, you can give it a try.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, I am unable to boot in live usb or cd,and recatux seems to be possible through that itself.

Comment: Do you know what the partition is for *root* mounted on your computer, eg sda1...sda2, etc?

Comment: Yes.. It is sda5...

Comment: "Nothing is working". Could you [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1162960/edit) the question and show us what exactly did you try?

Comment: In that case you might be able to boot into Ubuntu from your black grub screen. First you have to locate *root*. From the grub prompt run the command `ls (hd0,5)/`. Does that produce any output and do you see *vmlinuz* listed.

Comment: @Paul, it is present in (hd1, 5)

Comment: If you can't boot Live USB there must be something seriously wrong with your computer. Really you should forget posting a question about grub and focus on how to boot a Live USB.

Comment: I already posted an issue concerning that.. But right now if I am not able to move ahead of grub.. How will I fix it?

Comment: If you see `vmlinuz` and `initrd` present with that `ls` command I mentioned, you should be OK. I have to go out but I'll put up a solution when I get back in a few hours.

Comment: when I saw this screen all I did was type in 'exit' and hit enter... then I was able to bring up grub as normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your *grub* menu does not appear but the *grub* prompt with black screen shows, as long as your Linux system is still intact you can bypass the *grub* stage and boot directly into Ubuntu. Once you've done that you can easily fix *grub* from there. The steps to boot up are as follows:

a) First remove all external drives. Determine where your root partition is. In this case we already know it's *sda5*. If you don't know and you have one disk you can find out by typing `ls (hd0,x)/` trying different values for 'x' which is the number of the root partition on that disk. If you have more than one disk you may have to use *hd1* or a higher number if you don't know which disk Ubuntu is installed on. Once you hit the right disk/partition numbers you'll see listed the basic system folders and the 2 files *vmlinuz* and *initrd*. Note these 2 files are symlinks to the kernel and initrd image respectively but they must be present.

b) Now set the root with `set root=(hd0,5)` or whatever is the correct combination for disk/partition you found in (a). Press *Enter*.

c) Now we need to map the linux kernel to root. Type `linux /boot/vm`. At this point press the *Tab* button. The command will partially complete by offering a choice of (usually) 2 kernel versions. Take the higher number by typing it and press *Tab* button again. The whole kernel version number should autocomplete. You should be seeing something like `linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-55-generic` depending on kernel version. You still need to add root=/dev/sda5 to this line. So the whole command is `linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-55-generic root=/dev/sda5`. Press *Enter*.

d) Now we do similar for *initrd*. Type `initrd /boot/in` then press *Tab* button. Again it will offer 2 versions so choose the same version as in c) using *Tab* button again to autocomplete. You should see something like `initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-55-generic` as the complete command, depending on kernel version. Press *Enter*.

e) Then type `boot`. Press *Enter*.

After a a couple of minutes of splash screen activity you will eventually reach the user login screen, then proceed as normal. If during boot-up you reach the `intrafms` prompt and booting stops, you've probably mistyped something in the earlier stages and need to start again. Remember, this process **boots you into Linux**. Grub still needs a couple more commands to fix it once you're in.

Comment: Thanks! I needed a detailed explanation like this one! It worked!