# GRUB Error - minimal bash-like line editing

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, bash

I have dual boot my Dell 5577 with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04. Initially I allocated 100 GB to Ubuntu but I found it insufficient so I added extra 100 GB from my hard drive by creating a bootable pendrive of Ubuntu 19.10 and then booting into the live USB and using GParted to allocate extra space.
Everything went smoothly, I was able to add extra storage, then I restarted the system and boot into Ubuntu 18.04 and everything was working normally and it also displayed the new modified storage space. Now I booted into Windows, did some work, and then I tried to boot into Ubuntu but it got stuck at this grub error screen

[image]

I have tried these solutions but they didn't work

[Fix Minimal BASH like line editing is supported GRUB Error In Linux - It's FOSS](https://itsfoss.com/fix-minimal-bash-line-editing-supported-grub-error-linux)

[How to Fix Minimal BASH Like Line Editing is Supported GRUB Error In Linux? - GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-fix-minimal-bash-like-line-editing-is-supported-grub-error-in-linux/)

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Always better to use Windows to shrink NTFS partitions, and use gparted or other Linux tools for Linux partition changes. Did Windows do a major update or an UEFI update? That may have reset UEFI settings that need to be redone. Check UEFI settings. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: As long as you haven't wiped out your root partition you should be able to boot to Ubuntu from the Grub prompt. You first need to know/find out the root partition where your kernel resides using the `ls` command. [Read this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162960/cant-get-out-of-grub-terminal/1163243#1163243).

Comment: @PaulBenson none of the partitions show any boot folder and these files(vmlinuz and initrd) aren't visible anywhere

Comment: @Manav Khorasiya Sounds like you may have wiped your Ubuntu root partition. Boot into Live Ubuntu and run `sudo parted -l` and post output in your question, or a link to the output..

Comment: when I saw this screen all I did was type in 'exit' and hit enter... then I was able to bring up grub as normal.