# apt error while using boot-repair in a live session

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, boot-repair, live-environment

I have ubuntu 20.04 on my laptop. I installed windows alongside it and grub doesn`t work anymore (as expected), so I used a live ubuntu 20.04 flash to install and use [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).
Boot-repair successfully installed and opened but when it arrives at the step in which I should copy paste these commands in terminal:

[image]

this error occurs:

[image]

and boot-repair fails, so I cannot boot into my beloved highly customizable good old friend Ubuntu OS.

Comment: What happens when you try to boot up now? Eg, do you boot to Windows or nothing?

Comment: @PaulBenson if I choose windows in laptop boot options, it boots up in windows successfully
but booting in ubuntu opens an empty black page with grub2 (+blah blah) title and a grub promt like this:
grub>

Comment: See [my remedy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162960/cant-get-out-of-grub-terminal/1163243#1163243) in how to boot successfully to Ubuntu from  grub bash prompt. You will have to know which partition the root is on in advance. If you're not sure run `sudo parted -l` from Live Ubuntu and make a note of it. You still need to fix grub once you're booted, so let us know if you get that far.

Comment: @PaulBenson I did boot through grub bash prompt but I cannot fix grub.
I face this:
Generating grub configuration file ...
Script `/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new' contains no commands and will do nothing
Syntax errors are detected in generated GRUB config file.
Ensure that there are no errors in /etc/default/grub
and /etc/grub.d/* files or please file a bug report with
/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new file attached.

Comment: Wow! That was quick. You did boot to your hard drive? Boot up again (if not already), then run `sudo update-grub`  followed by `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` or whatever the correct disk notation is.then reboot.

Comment: Honestly I did it several times before your comment, searching for solutions. and the update-grub that you mentioned do not work

Comment: @PaulBenson this is the error: Script `/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new' contains no commands and will do nothing
Syntax errors are detected in generated GRUB config file.
Ensure that there are no errors in /etc/default/grub
and /etc/grub.d/* files or please file a bug report with
/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new file attached.

Comment: What happens if you boot up and run just the 'grub-install' command. What message is given? While you are in Ubuntu, can you run `sudo parted -l` and post output into question.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the failing package it is useless in the state it is in. `apt remove yaru-theme-gnome-shell` This should allow it to complete the install of the packages the `boot-repair` wants installed. Then repeat the command it told you to do.